# How do I prevent an ad built in Adscript from intercepting a scroll event in browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using AdScript to build this ad. When I'm previewing my creative on a test page I am unable to scroll the page. Here's my code:

```
  // SET CLIPPING MASK FOR BG IMAGES
  var adHeight = [690,578,430,306];
  var curState = 0;

  var clip = new Rectangle ({
    stage: stage,
    x: 0, y: 0,
    width: '100%', height: adHeight[curState],
    fillStyle: '#ff0055'
   });


    var bg_0 = new Sprite ({
        stage: stage,
        path: 'path/to/img',
        x: '0%', y: '0%',
        width: '100%',
        clipObjects: [clip],
        display: false
    });

    var ratio_0 = 788/1400;

    bg_0.set ({ height: ratio_0 * bg_0.width });
```

When I drag my finger over the ad, the page does not scroll. However, when I drag my finger elsewhere on the page, the scroll works as expected. Is there a way to prevent the ad unit from disabling the scroll?

Comment: It's nice that you added some code to illustrate your problem. But to get a useful answer, you should tell where the `Sprite` class you're using comes from. Is it from a well-known framework or something internal?

Comment: Also can you share a link to the `AdScripts` library? I couldn't find anything relevant online on that library. That should help diagnose your issue.

Comment: AdScripts is __probably__ Adcade's JS library. I wonder if there's a tag for this?